# Tkinter infinitely generating and moving images (making sure every image is falling all the way from top to bottom)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I'm trying to make a fruit ninja game. My current goal is to generate infinite, falling fruits on my canvas (4 column in total, random speed), and several of them appear at once (not like generate one after the other one is gone). And get track of each of them, so that later on I can do collision (if the knives are hitting them or not), and destroy them if so.

Previously, I have tried `root.after` method but it obviously won't work with my code because once the function is called again, the variable will be assigned to a new photo, thus the previous fruit will disappear.

I'm thinking of using recursion in this version of code I'm showing. It doesn't work properly: the fruit will be generated, but like the `after()` method, once it reaches to the point, it will disappear, and the second fruit can only be generated after the previous one disappears.

**Here's my code:**

```
from tkinter import *
import time
from random import randint

score = 0

def create_fruits():
    while score < 21:
        #choose random fruits with different possibilities
        which_fruit = randint(1,11)

        #import fuits and bomb images
        global this_fruit

        if which_fruit == 1 or which_fruit == 10 or which_fruit == 11:
            this_fruit = PhotoImage(file = "bomb.png")
        elif which_fruit == 2:
            this_fruit = PhotoImage(file = "apple.png")
        elif which_fruit == 3:
            this_fruit = PhotoImage(file = "banana.png")
        elif which_fruit == 4:
            this_fruit = PhotoImage(file = "cherry.png")
        elif which_fruit == 5:
            this_fruit = PhotoImage(file = "blueberry.png")
        elif which_fruit == 6:
            this_fruit = PhotoImage(file = "pear.png")
        elif which_fruit == 7:
            this_fruit = PhotoImage(file = "lemon.png")
        elif which_fruit == 8:
            this_fruit = PhotoImage(file = "watermelon.png")
        elif which_fruit == 9:
            this_fruit = PhotoImage(file = "mango.png")

        #randomly generate which colum (four in total) the fruits will be
        choose_position = randint (1,4)

        global x_position

        if choose_position == 1:
            x_position = 112.5
        elif choose_position == 2:
            x_position = 287.5
        elif choose_position == 3:
            x_position = 462.5
        else:
            x_position = 637.5

        #place the fruit image on the canvas
        global my_photo
        my_photo = canvas.create_image (x_position,0, image = this_fruit, anchor = 's')

        x_volocity = 0
        y_volocity = randint (5,10)

        while True:
            coords = canvas.coords(my_photo) #get coordinates of the fruit picture
            print (coords)
            #move the fruit
            canvas.move (my_photo,x_volocity,y_volocity)
            canvas.update()
            time.sleep(0.01)

            if coords [1] >= 400:
                create_fruits()


#create game area
root = Tk ()

canvas = Canvas (root, height = 1200, width = 800, bg = 'black')
#canvas.create_image(0,0, image = bg_image, anchor = 'nw')
canvas.pack()

create_fruits()

mainloop()
```

Here's another version I tried: (like assign the second fruit to a new variable and then call the recursion). The result is that once the first fruit reaches the point the program will crash (like not respond).

```
from tkinter import *
import time
from random import randint

score = 0

def create_fruits():
    while score < 21:
        #choose random fruits with different possibilities
        which_fruit = randint(1,11)

        #import fuits and bomb images
        global this_fruit

        if which_fruit == 1 or which_fruit == 10 or which_fruit == 11:
            this_fruit = PhotoImage(file = "bomb.png")
        elif which_fruit == 2:
            this_fruit = PhotoImage(file = "apple.png")
        elif which_fruit == 3:
            this_fruit = PhotoImage(file = "banana.png")
        elif which_fruit == 4:
            this_fruit = PhotoImage(file = "cherry.png")
        elif which_fruit == 5:
            this_fruit = PhotoImage(file = "blueberry.png")
        elif which_fruit == 6:
            this_fruit = PhotoImage(file = "pear.png")
        elif which_fruit == 7:
            this_fruit = PhotoImage(file = "lemon.png")
        elif which_fruit == 8:
            this_fruit = PhotoImage(file = "watermelon.png")
        elif which_fruit == 9:
            this_fruit = PhotoImage(file = "mango.png")

        #randomly generate which colum (four in total) the fruits will be
        choose_position = randint (1,4)

        global x_position

        if choose_position == 1:
            x_position = 112.5
        elif choose_position == 2:
            x_position = 287.5
        elif choose_position == 3:
            x_position = 462.5
        else:
            x_position = 637.5

        #place the fruit image on the canvas
        global my_photo
        my_photo = canvas.create_image (x_position,0, image = this_fruit, anchor = 's')

        x_volocity = 0
        y_volocity = randint (5,10)

        while True:
            coords = canvas.coords(my_photo) #get coordinates of the fruit picture
            print (coords)
            #move the fruit
            canvas.move (my_photo,x_volocity,y_volocity)
            canvas.update()
            time.sleep(0.01)

            if coords [1] >= 400:
                create_fruits()



                #choose random fruits with different possibilities
                which_fruit2 = randint(1,11)

                #import fuits and bomb images
                global this_fruit2

                if which_fruit2 == 1 or which_fruit2 == 10 or which_fruit2 == 11:
                    this_fruit2 = PhotoImage(file = "bomb.png")
                elif which_fruit == 2:
                    this_fruit2 = PhotoImage(file = "apple.png")
                elif which_fruit == 3:
                    this_fruit2 = PhotoImage(file = "banana.png")
                elif which_fruit == 4:
                    this_fruit2 = PhotoImage(file = "cherry.png")
                elif which_fruit == 5:
                    this_fruit2 = PhotoImage(file = "blueberry.png")
                elif which_fruit == 6:
                    this_fruit2 = PhotoImage(file = "pear.png")
                elif which_fruit == 7:
                    this_fruit2 = PhotoImage(file = "lemon.png")
                elif which_fruit == 8:
                    this_fruit2 = PhotoImage(file = "watermelon.png")
                elif which_fruit == 9:
                    this_fruit2 = PhotoImage(file = "mango.png")

                #randomly generate which colum (four in total) the fruits will be
                choose_position2 = randint (1,4)

                global x_position2

                if choose_position2 == 1:
                    x_position = 112.5
                elif choose_position2 == 2:
                    x_position2 = 287.5
                elif choose_position2 == 3:
                    x_position2 = 462.5
                else:
                    x_position2 = 637.5

                #place the fruit image on the canvas
                global my_photo2
                my_photo2 = canvas.create_image (x_position2,0, image = this_fruit2, anchor = 's')

                x_volocity2 = 0
                y_volocity2 = randint (5,10)

                while True:
                    coords2 = canvas.coords(my_photo2) #get coordinates of the fruit picture
                    print (coords2)
                    #move the fruit
                    canvas.move (my_photo2,x_volocity2,y_volocity2)
                    canvas.update()
                    time.sleep(0.01)

                    if coords2 >= 400:
                        create_fruits()

#create game area
root = Tk ()

canvas = Canvas (root, height = 1200, width = 800, bg = 'black')
#canvas.create_image(0,0, image = bg_image, anchor = 'nw')
canvas.pack()

create_fruits()

mainloop()
```

Here's the third version of my code (with `after` method). In the code, I also tried to use list to get track of fruits and delete them after but it doesn't seem working (and I'm not sure why).

```
#make the fruits appear on the screen
def create_fruits():
    #choose random fruits with different possibilities
    which_fruit = randint(1,11)
    
    #import fuits and bomb images
    global this_fruit
    
    if which_fruit == 1 or which_fruit == 10 or which_fruit == 11:
        this_fruit = PhotoImage(file = "bomb.png")
    elif which_fruit == 2:
        this_fruit = PhotoImage(file = "apple.png")
    elif which_fruit == 3:
        this_fruit = PhotoImage(file = "banana.png")
    elif which_fruit == 4:
        this_fruit = PhotoImage(file = "cherry.png")
    elif which_fruit == 5:
        this_fruit = PhotoImage(file = "blueberry.png")
    elif which_fruit == 6:
        this_fruit = PhotoImage(file = "pear.png")
    elif which_fruit == 7:
        this_fruit = PhotoImage(file = "lemon.png")
    elif which_fruit == 8:
        this_fruit = PhotoImage(file = "watermelon.png")
    elif which_fruit == 9:
        this_fruit = PhotoImage(file = "mango.png")

    #randomly generate which colum (four in total) the fruits will be
    choose_position = randint (1,4)
    
    global x_position
    
    if choose_position == 1:
        x_position = 112.5
    elif choose_position == 2:
        x_position = 287.5
    elif choose_position == 3:
        x_position = 462.5
    else:
        x_position = 637.5

    #create a list to store fruit images
    global fruits_list
    fruits_list = []
    
    
    
    #append it to the list
    fruits_list.append(this_fruit)
   
    
    #place the fruit image on the canvas
    global my_photo
    my_photo = canvas.create_image (x_position,0, image = this_fruit, anchor = 's')
    #global root
    #repeatedly generate fruit images every 3 second
    root.after(3000,create_fruits)
    
    
    
    

#nake fruits' animation  
#let one fruit keep moving while the second fruit pears  
def move_fruits():
    
    #set the moving speed
    x_volocity = 0
    y_volocity = randint (5,10)
    
    #try to make two fruits moving at the same time on the screen
    for i in range (0,len(fruits_list)-1):
        while True:
            coords = canvas.coords(fruits_list[i]) #get coordinates of the fruit picture
            print (coords)
            #move the fruit
            canvas.move (fruits_list[i],x_volocity,y_volocity)
            canvas.update()
            time.sleep(0.01)
            #assign this fruit to finished fruit to delete it from the list later
            finished_fruit = fruits_list[i]
            #check is the fruit is outside of the boarder, if so, delete if from the list and countinue on the second fruit
            if coords [i] >= 1400:
                fruits_list.remove(finished_fruit)
```

Comment: Can you show the version with `.after`? The problem is most likely because you use reuse same variable. I think it would be better if you would append the current moving fruits to a list to keep track of them.

Comment: Thanks. I posted the ```after``` version of the code and tried the list (but I'm new to coding so I honestly don't know how)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made a few changes to your code including removing unnecessary if-statements (instead storing it in `dict`) and removing the infinite while loop.

```py
from tkinter import *
from random import randint
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

#make the fruits appear on the screen
def create_fruits():
    
    global fruits_list

    #choose random fruits with different possibilities
    which_fruit = randint(1,3)

    this_fruit = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(fruit_dic[which_fruit]))
    #randomly generate which colum (four in total) the fruits will be
    choose_position = randint (1,4)
    
    x_position = x_positions_dic[choose_position]  # choose the position from dict

    my_photo = canvas.create_image(x_position, 80, image = this_fruit, anchor = 's')

    #append it to the list(image_id, x position, image)
    fruits_list.append([my_photo, randint(5,10), this_fruit])

    #repeatedly generate fruit images every 3 second
    root.after(3000,create_fruits)
    

def move_fruits():
    
    for fruit in fruits_list:
        
        canvas.move(fruit[0], 0, fruit[1])

        if canvas.bbox(fruit[0])[3] >= canvas.winfo_height()+100:
            canvas.delete(fruit[0])
            fruits_list.remove(fruit)

    root.after(10, move_fruits)  # calls the move_fruits after every 10 seconds
    
root = Tk()

canvas = Canvas (root, height = 1200, width = 800, bg = 'black')
canvas.pack()

fruits_list = []

x_positions_dic = {1: 112.5, 2: 287.5, 3: 462.5, 4:637.5}
fruit_dic = {1: r"imag\fruit1" , 2: r"img\fruit2" , 3: r"img\fruit3"} # your path here

create_fruits()
move_fruits()

root.mainloop()
```